# Azure ARM Templates, VNET Integration of a Site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I'm mamanging a creation of a whole system in Azure cloud.
It is possible to set VNET integration of a Site Resource (Webapp or Functions) within templates ?

Attaching a screenshot of the settings that I'd manage.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible to set VNET integration of a Site Resource (Webapp or Functions) within templates?

The following template could be used to create website and connect it to an existing VNET, please refer to it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and instance size. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    },
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of an existing Azure VNet which has a Gateway Subnet already, and is in the resource group you are going to deploy."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
          "type": "virtualNetworkConnections",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "vnetResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And then from [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/), we could find there is a **virtualNetworkConnections** node under the site.

[image]

Comment: under SiteConfig node of the website resource, there is an option for vnetName.  This has worked for me before as well.