# How to configure an existing web app and virtual network in azure using the ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I have a created a Web app in the Azure portal and i also have a virtual network with a vnet gateway attached to the virtual network.

Is it possible to integrate the **vnet**(with existing gateway) to the **Azure Web app**. If so how to do this with the help of **ARM Template**??

Also how to **integrate the virtual network to Azure Web App** in case if the virtual network is in **another Resource group**???

Answer (score 1):

This should point you [the right way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites) .

If the vnet is in another resource group you might add the app server's service principal to that vnet to create it fully automated  - If the vnet is one with your privileges it shouldn't matter though.

Previous rather outdated answer: [Azure ARM Templates, VNET Integration of a Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624203/azure-arm-templates-vnet-integration-of-a-site)

Comment: hey aheumaier, thanks for the reply... and if there is an existing vnet and a web app then how to link it with the ARM templates

Comment: just add the vnets resourceId to the webbapp template as documented. ` az network vnet show -n myNetwork -o json` let you retrive the resourceID:  "id": "/subscriptions/$mySubscriptionID$/resourceGroups/$myResourceGroup$/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$myNetworkName$"

Comment: Thanks for the reply aheumaier, but there is no parameter stating "vnetid" in the web app template format so that i can specify my resourceID in the web app ARM template directly. If we can add the resourceID to web app template please give me a sample template...

Comment: hey guys is there any other way to add the existing vnet in another resource group to the web app that you are going to create using ARM template in a different resource group and if so. how ? share an sample template